# Why did this flight descend way below usual path?

Tags: flight-path, descent

I flew on UAL2086 last night which is a regularly scheduled flight from KIAH to KLAS, this particular plane was a 737-900 - N79402. We took off early and had no issues until we arrived in Arizona when we descended to 20000 ft the flight attendants asked everyone to be seated for safety reasons. There was some bumps which could’ve been turbulence but overall didn’t seem serious. Capt eventually came over intercom asking the FAs to check in. Nothing else was really said until we were 70 miles or so from KLAS. Upon arrival the FAs said there would be airport staff waiting with any questions we may have had regarding the incident but when leaving the plane no information was given or known. We stayed at 20000 ft well before usual descent procedures as we were still over 300 miles out. I reached out to United regarding what happened but does any of this seem odd to you guys? [image]

[image]

Comment: @MichaelHall I believe that is what the OP is asking...what happened. If they were not told of what happened by UA, I would say that the best choice is to see if Audio is available for the flight on one sites that do that. However the second screen shot is confusing because it doesn't cover the period of time which whatever occured. The OP should update the second screen shot to show what happened between 930pm and 10:00pm. not during the initial take off.

Comment: I apologize as it won’t allow me to add anymore photos beyond one. I’ve since edited it and added when the descent began. I’ve looked for audio but haven’t found anything yet.

Comment: ahh yeah limitation of a new poster. the top chart with speed and altitude is more important but the other stuff shows about a 750 fpm descent from 30k to 20k.  just an additional point on the upper chart the sequence of the descent looks kinda normal, but speed isn't as smooth as I would guess it should be for a controlled descent. the speed briefly increases when the descent is initiated, then is a bit unstable until acceleration is used to stop the descent. after the descent to 22k and later 20k.  velocity which I'm thinking is ground speed smooths out, so maybe they lost an engine.

Comment: That tail number was flying today on normal routes so not sure why the fast descent. https://www.liveatc.net/search/?icao=klas on that site you can listen to archived audio though a small link in each section.  IAH to LAS would have arrived from the South East so that is where your flight is lrobably recorded.

Comment: Previous flight schedules with this route and various other routes show this was out of norm. The lowest I’ve found was a flight from the last two weeks that descended to 28k for approximately 11 minutes before entering true descent phase. Traffic wasn’t a issue unless it was something not showing on radar. I’m a frequent flyer and a aircraft mechanic and this was not normal to me.

Comment: It's very telling that the airline admitted that there was an "incident", yet didn't say what it was.  Puzzling... no unusual pressurization changes?

Comment: Quick skim through the QRH shows: 1. LE FLAPS TRANSIT, descend to FL200 and cycle flaps. 2. Elevator tab vibration, reduce airspeed until it stops, 15 degree bank angle limitation above FL200. 3. Engine restart, but the OP should have noticed that.